# error installing sodium package on linux EC2 - unable to load shared object

Tags: r, libsodium

I am trying to install the `sodium` R package on an AWS Linux (fedora) EC2 instance. The `libsodium` lib  is installed and lives here:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx]$ sudo find / -iname libsodium.*
/usr/local/lib/libsodium.a
/usr/local/lib/libsodium.la
/usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23.3.0
/usr/local/lib/libsodium.so
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libsodium.pc
...
```

In R I ran the following commands which throw an error. As far as I can tell from the messages, `libsodium` is not found.

```
> Sys.setenv(PKG_CONFIG_PATH= "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig")
> install.packages("sodium")
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
...

** package ‘sodium’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include
Using PKG_LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -lsodium
** libs
...

** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sodium’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/sodium/libs/sodium.so':
  libsodium.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
...
```

**I am not well-versed in linux and do not understand what to do now. For example, do I need to set any other environment vars etc.? Any ideas? :)**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you either have the wrong version of `libsodium` or it's install in the wrong place.

If it was installed using `yum` you can check what version is installed by running `yum info libsodium-devel`

According to the package requirements https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sodium/index.html

> SystemRequirements:   libsodium (>= 1.0.3)

I think the latest version of `libsodium-devel` AWS have on their repos is `Version     : 0.4.5`

To fix this you need to `yum install` the `libsodium-devel` from another repo that has a later version such as the lux repo: https://pkgs.org/download/libsodium-devel

First add the lux repo to yum:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://repo.iotti.biz/CentOS/6/noarch/lux-release-6-3.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-LUX
```

I then had to edit the `.repo` file to point to the right place for some reason. edit this file `/etc/yum.repos.d/lux.repo` to contain the following:

```
[lux]
name=CentOS $releasever - $basearch - Lux
baseurl=http://repo.iotti.biz/CentOS/6
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-LUX
```

once you've done that you should be good to `yum install` the package:

`sudo yum install libsodium-devel`

Then the R `install.packages("sodium")` should complete successfully.